# Std::string get assigned by a function returning a char *

Tags: c++

### Update: for the getValue function I have no control, so is there anything I can do from my side?

I have a kind of dumb question about string and char * basic.

I'm using a function that returns a char * value,

```
const char *getValue(const char *key)
{
    //if key found, and valueString is a string
      return valueString.c_str();
    //else
      return NULL;
}
```

then I initialized a string to hold the return value,

```
std::string value = getValue(key);
```

problem is, whenever the value is not found, which means the function returns NULL, my assignment line will run into an exception. But when there is a legal return value, everything is working fine.

I'm wondering
1. Is this usage totally wrong? means I should never mix char * with string?
2. If not, then when there is a legal pointer returned, does my string automatically make a copy and store it?
3. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The best way to do this depends on what `getValue` is supposed to do. You can return `""` instead of `NULL`, or throw an exception.

Comment: I would return a `string` instead of a `char*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have no control over what the `getValue()` function does, you need to check the return value for NULL before assigning it to the `std::string`.

```
std::string value;  // value is an empty string
const char *retVal = NULL;

if( ( retVal = getValue(key) ) != NULL ) {
  value.assign( retVal );
}
```

Comment: Not to pollute the code with new variables you can declare `retVal` in the `if`: `if ( const char* retVal = getValue(key) ) { value.assign( retVal );` The solution is not wonderful... but the issue is not in user code but rather in the interface provided by the library. +1 (Another alternative would be wrapping the function: `std::string getValueStr( key_type const & k ) { const char* r = getValue( k ); return r ? r : ""; }`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if `valueString` is local to that function, using the pointer you return will give undefined behavior.

Second, whether returning a null pointer is reasonable will depend on how you use that pointer, of which you've told us nothing.

Unless you absolutely, positively must fiddle with pointers, just return a string and make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: thanks for replying, sorry I didn't mention that I have no control over that function I'm using, all I can do is to make the usage correct.  BTW the return variable is not local.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a goot idea to report of occurrence of error (if key *not* found) by returning NULL. In this case you should generate meaningful exception inside the function. Something like `NotFoundEx`.

if you have no control over that function, you should wrap it into your safe code:

```
const char* getSafeValue(const char *key)
{
  const char* value = getValue(key);
  if(value == NULL)
    throw NotFoundEx();

  return value;
}


std::string value = getSafeValue(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with `std::string` values anyway, I would just return a `std::string` instead of a `char*`:

```
std::string getValue(const char *key) 
{ 
    if (key found)
        return valueString; 
    else 
        return std::string(); 
}
```

Comment: In that case, ideally, `boost::optional<std::string>`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `std::string` with an out of bound value.  `(char *)` might not be the ideal way to do it (see `boost::optional` for a better way), but it will work (assuming you aren't using a stack-local variable) — *if* you check for the out of bound value.  That is, the problem here is not really mixing `(char *)` and `std::string`, it is that you aren't checking for "not found" but blindly assuming something sensible will happen in that case.

Don't assume; determine what you need to do if the key is not found, and check for the `NULL` (or other out of band, if you choose to use something else).

Answer (score 0):

First question: where does the data come from?  You cann't return the
results of `c_str()` on a local variable; it's undefined behavior, and
you've just been unlucky that it seems to work.  If `valueString` is
just a copy of some more long lasting data, then you can call `c_str`
directly on it.  More generally, however: whatever you return, you'll
have to verify that it is valid before trying to use it.  The simplest
solution (but not always possible) is just to use a sentinal value in
the `string`, e.g.:

```
std::string
getValue( std::string const& key )
{
    //  ...
    return condition ? valueString : std:;string();
}
```

for example, using an empty string as the sentinal.

If the semantics of the function don't provide a convenient sentinal
value—for example, if the function can return an empty string as a
valid value—then you'll have to do something else.

If the return value is the result of a lookup in some long
lived container, then you may be able to return a pointer to the element
in the container.  In general, however, pointers pose the problem of
what they point to; if you don't have something whose lifetime is
sufficient, then you don't want to use a pointer.

Another possibility is for the caller to provide the default value:

```
std::string
getValue( std::string const& key, std::string const& ifNotFound )
{
    // ...
    return condition ? valueString : ifNotFound;
}
```

This shifts the responsibility of defining the sentinal off to the
callee.  In cases like string, there's almost always some value that the
callee can't do anything with, and so can use as a sentinal.

The most general alternative is some sort of `Fallible` or `Maybe`
class: a class object which combines a status (typically just a `bool`)
and an instance of the actual data type.  Whether the data are valid or
not depends on the value of the status, so you still have to check that:

```
Fallible<std::string>
getValue( std::string const& key )
{
    //  ...
    return condition
        ? Fallible<std::string>( valueString )
        : Fallible<std::string>();
}
```

This often works out well internally as well:

```
Fallible<std::string>
getValue( std::string const& key )
{
    Fallible<std::string> results;
    //  ...
    // At some point, I've got a valid return value, so I do:
        results.validate( valueString );
    // in a condition, of course...
    return results;
}
```

(Just an example of a frequent and convenient pattern.)